# Caddy Server error: "Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'if'"

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

New to using `Caddy` server and fighting with the `Caddyfile`...

[This](https://pastebin.com/J3Ud2qvP) is the current Caddyfile that I have; when I type "`caddy`" from the command line, from within the same folder, I get the following error:

```
Caddyfile:3 - Error during parsing: Unknown directive 'if'
```

When I look at the docs for `http.redir` [here](https://caddyserver.com/docs/redir) the very last example on the page seems to show that I have the syntax correct? *confused*

Answer (score 2):

From [the bold text of the docs](https://caddyserver.com/tutorial/caddyfile):

> The first line of the Caddyfile is always the address of the site to serve.

Instead, your first line appears to be a directive, `redir`, which is confusing Caddy.

I would recommend going through the beginner tutorials to learn how the Caddyfile is structured.